# how to do template matching OCR in opencv python

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

iam now working on simple character recognition with template matching in python opencv with cv2.matchTemplate. so far this is my code only the matching process :

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

im = cv2.imread('test.png')
imgray = cv2.cvtColor(im,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(imgray, 255, 1, 1, 11, 2)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL,
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

for contour in contours:
if cv2.contourArea(contour) > 50:# remove the small contour
 [x, y, w, h] = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
 if h > 20:
   cv2.rectangle(im, (x, y), (x+w, y+h), (0, 0, 255), 1)
   print x, y, w, h
   cropped = im[y:y+h, x:y+h]#crop the roi region

 res = 0
 character = 0
```

this is the part that i confused, the template matching part :

```
 imref = cv2.imread('a.jpg')#reads the template image
 result = cv2.matchTemplate(cropped, imref, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED)
 res = result
 character = 'A'
 print "match"+character


 cv2.imshow('im',im)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
```

my picture to match with template basicly the same, i made both of them in word using same font and pixel size which is 24x26, but all i got is the character that i write in

```
 character = 'A'
```

can anyone tell me what i did wrong?

Comment: you're missing a step. you have to use minMaxLoc on the result image, and then decide using the distance, if it was a match or not.

Comment: sorry berak , i miss typed it should be 'a.jpg'

Comment: and then again, character recognition is anything but simple, given the number of existing fonts, etc. if you think, you can do ocr with plain template matching - no way.

Comment: you mean like "min_val,max_val,min_loc,max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(result)"? and then how to decide using the distance and decide if its match or not?sorry cause iam new to this opencv-python

Comment: please start to [RTFM](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html#object-detection) now !

Comment: thanks berak for the answer, and yeah i already rad the manual and still doest ring a bell its quite frustating to find the right answer hehee

Comment: "the best matches can be found as global minimums (when CV_TM_SQDIFF was used) or maximums (when CV_TM_CCORR or CV_TM_CCOEFF was used)"